# Why can't rsync hard link certain files on a Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, rsync

I am running rsync to sync files from Linux to a mounted Mac OS X (HFS+) disk image.

I am getting a lot of errors of the form:

```
rsync: link "/Volumes/Archive/blahblahblah" => blahblahblah failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

I tried manually running `ln` on the paths mentioned directly on the Mac and get the same error.  Yet I have hundreds of other hard links which are successfully being transferred.

I checked the permissions on the file on both the file and the directory that the hard link is supposed to be created in, and have permission.  I can create a hard link from a different file to the same file name as was supposed to be created, so the problem appears to be with the file that a hard link is supposed to be created for.  It is a normal file, and in Finder when I "Get Info" it is not "Locked" nor do I see any reason why a hard link should fail.

On the Linux side, I ran `lsattr` on the file in question and see `--------------e---` which appears to be a normal attribute that shouldn't cause this issue.